# get $_POST name and value in php foreach loop to build a long string

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert, radio-button

I need to put alot of radio button values into the database, so I post 300 values to a processing page, where I need to sort things out a bit.

I want to be able to differentiate between each radio buttons value and name (when posted) so I can insert them into the database. This is my code: (but maybe i need a jagged array?)

VALUE:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
$value = $value.',';
}
```

POST NAME: ???

```
foreach ($_POST[name]?? as ??? => $postname)
{
$postname = $postname.',';
}
```

Then I need to differentiate between the value and name and put in the correct columns in the database:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabke SELECT '$longstring' or die(mysql_error());;
```

Comment: what is your table `tabke` structure?

Comment: `jagged array`? What is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you want to insert using `SELECT`, as this construct is to insert from [already existing table data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html). You can, however, insert multiple `VALUES` with a single statement. You'd need to do :

```
// you should filter out values from your $_POST...
$ignoredFields = array('submit', ...);
$fields = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($ignoredFields));

$values = array();
foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
   $key = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
   $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
   $values[] =  "'{$key}', '{$value}'";
}

// creation the insert string
$query = 'INSERT INTO `tabke` (`key`,`value`) VALUES ('.implode(,'),(', $values).')';
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

** **Note** ** : I suppose that your table `tabke` look something like

```
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| key     | varchar(64)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| value   | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As long as your query does not extend [max_allowed_packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601142/php-and-mysql-maximum-variable-length), this will work just fine. In case your data exceed that size, you can simply use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and iterate through the chunks and building the `INSERT` with each chunks.

Comment: any field that you need to ignore from your form. For example, if you have a reset button (`name="reset"`) and a submit button (`name="submit"`), you would have `$ignoredFields = array('reset', 'submit');`. For example.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be $key, but there will only be one post per distinct radio "Group", also you should be sanitizing your inputs for SQL injection.